# Problem when trying to plot two histograms using fill aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot two histograms by using the fill aesthetic and a specific column with two levels. However, instead of displaying both desired histograms, my code displays one histogram with the whole data and another only for the second classification. I don't know if there is a problem in my syntax neither if this is some kind of tricky issue.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    db1 <- data.frame(type=rep("A",100),val=rnorm(n=100,mean=50,sd=10))
    db2 <- data.frame(type=rep("B",150),val=rnorm(n=150,mean=50,sd=10))
    dbf <- bind_rows(db1,db2)

    P1 <- ggplot(db1, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram()
    P2 <- ggplot(db2, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram()
    PF <- ggplot(dbf, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram()
```

I want to get this, P1 and P2

```
ggplot(db1, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram(fill="red", alpha=0.5) + geom_histogram(data=db2, aes(x=val),fill="green", alpha=0.5)
```

What I want

[image]

But the code I think should work, P1 and P2 with the fill aesthetic for column val

```
ggplot(dbf, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=type), alpha=0.5)
```

My code

[image]

Produces the combination of PF and P2

```
ggplot(dbf, aes(x=val)) + geom_histogram(fill="red", alpha=0.5) + geom_histogram(data=db2, aes(x=val),fill="green", alpha=0.5)
```

What I get

[image]

Any help or idea will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to pass position = "identity" to your geom_histogram function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

db1 <- data.frame(type=rep("A",100),val=rnorm(n=100,mean=50,sd=10))
db2 <- data.frame(type=rep("B",150),val=rnorm(n=150,mean=50,sd=10))
dbf <- bind_rows(db1,db2)

ggplot(dbf, aes(x=val, fill = type)) + geom_histogram(alpha=0.5, position = "identity")
```

[image: overlapping histogram]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the default setting was to stack bars.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to show the overlap via the color combination? I'm not sure how to force geom_histogram to show the overlap, but geom_density does do what you want. You can play with the bandwidth (bw) to show more or less detail.

```
dbf %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = val, fill = type) +
  geom_density(alpha = .5, bw = .5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","green"))
```